# Pandas: Dynamically deciede which column to update based on another column's value

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say we have the following dataframe

```
    handle  image_src   image_position  image_src_1 image_src_2 image_src_3
0        a       img1                1         None        None        None
1        b       img2                2         None        None        None
2        c       img3                3         None        None        None
```

How can we convert this datafame into this?

```
    handle  image_src   image_position  image_src_1 image_src_2 image_src_3
0        a       img1                1         img1        None        None
1        b       img2                2         None        img2        None
2        c       img3                3         None        None        img3
```

Basically I want to fill the `image_src_{image_position}` column based on the value of `image_position` of each row.

I come up with a solution which involves manually iterating over the whole dataframe, like this

```
data = [
    {"handle": "a","image_src": "img1","image_position": 1,"image_src_1": None,"image_src_2": None,"image_src_3": None},
    {"handle": "b","image_src": "img2","image_position": 2,"image_src_1": None,"image_src_2": None,"image_src_3": None},
    {"handle": "c","image_src": "img3","image_position": 3,"image_src_1": None,"image_src_2": None,"image_src_3": None}
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

for index in range(0, len(df)):
    row = df.iloc[index]
    
    position = row["image_position"].astype("int64")
    
    df.loc[index, f"image_src_{position}"] = row["image_src"]
```

But as iterating over the whole dataframe is a bad thing, how can I imporove this?

Answer (score 3):

First that came to my mind was `.pivot()` function. Though this might not be the exact thing you wanted, — the original `image_src` column would be dropped, the column naming would slightly differ and `nan` might need handling, — still it's rather a short solution.

```py
(df.pivot(index=['handle', 'image_position'],  # to keep these columns intact
          columns='image_src',
          values='image_src')
   .add_prefix('image_src_')
   .reset_index())
```

What I got:

|  | handle | image_position | image_src_img1 | image_src_img2 | image_src_img3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a | 1 | img1 | nan | nan |
| 1 | b | 2 | nan | img2 | nan |
| 2 | c | 3 | nan | nan | img3 |

Another take is to use `image_position` column as an index for the new columns, thus it would be dropped too. Also you may want to replace `nan` with `None`:

```py
import numpy as np

(df.pivot(index='handle',
          columns='image_position',
          values='image_src')
   .add_prefix('image_src_')
   .replace({np.nan: None})
   .reset_index())
```

Goes like this:

|  | handle | image_src_1 | image_src_2 | image_src_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a | img1 | None | None |
| 1 | b | None | img2 | None |
| 2 | c | None | None | img3 |

Answer (score 1):

here is one way to do it, assuming that the suffix to the image name is not associated to the column name suffix. Instead its the image position to decide the column

```
#melt the dataframe
df2=df.melt(id_vars=['handle','image_src','image_position'])

# identify the rows where the image_position matches the column suffix
df2['idx']=(df2['variable'].str.rsplit('_',1, expand=True)[1]).astype(int).eq(df2['image_position'])

# updates the value column with the images name
df2.loc[df2['idx']==True, 'value'] = df2['image_src']

#pivot to reverse the melt
df2.pivot(index=['handle','image_src','image_position'], columns='variable', values='value').reset_index()
```

```
variable    handle  image_src   image_position  image_src_1     image_src_2     image_src_3
0                a  img1                     1         img1             None    None
1                b  img2                     2         None             img2    None
2                c  img3                     3         None             None    img3
```